# Flatten SQL for 4 tables

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012

In SQL Server 2012, I have four tables that look like:

`Issues`:

```
IssueID | IssueTitle
1       | Light Bulb Burnt Out
2       | Thermostat not working
```

`LocationTypes`:

```
TypeID | Type
1        | Building
2        | Floor
3        | Room
```

`Locations`:

```
 LocaltionID | TypeID    | Location      | ParentLocation
 0           |  1        | default       | 0 
 1           |  1        | Sears Tower   | 0 
 2           |  1        | IDS           | 0
 3           |  2        | Floor 1       | 1
 4           |  2        | Floor 2       | 1
 5           |  2        | Floor 3       | 1
 6           |  2        | Floor 4       | 1
 7           |  2        | Floor 5       | 1
 8           |  2        | Floor 6       | 1
 9           |  2        | Floor 7       | 1
 10          |  2        | Floor 8       | 1
 108         |  3        | Room 101      | 3
 109         |  3        | Room 102      | 3
 110         |  3        | Room 110      | 3
 111         |  3        | Room 202      | 4
 112         |  3        | Room 300      | 5
 175         |  2        | 1st Floor     | 2
 185         |  2        | 2nd Floor     | 2
 186         |  3        | Suite 295     | 185
```

`IssueLocations`:

```
IssueID | LocationId 
1       | 1        
1       | 5        
1       | 112   
2       | 2
2       | 185
```

And what I want to do is combine the tables so that I end up with one row for each issuer, with field names as column headers and the field values, so I end up with:

Result:

```
IssueID  | IssueTitle             | Building     | Floor     | Room
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
1        | Light Bulb Burnt Out   | Sears Tower  | Floor 1   | Room 300 
2        | Thermostat not working | IDS          | 2nd Floor |
```

Notice the second issue doesn't have a room (no locations are required), location less issues are valid. Note other constraints might cause a required location but I don't think that is not relevant for this question.

Comment: Show us your attempts and efforts so far - and tell us where you're stuck!

Comment: I think you're missing a `TypeID` in your `IssueLocations` table.

Comment: @Dave.Gugg Issues -> IssueLocations -> Location -> LocationTypes

Comment: No @Dave.Gugg I don't think I am.  I can get to the TypeID if I want via a join, so don't think I need to put that extra data in that table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Pivot` to **transpose** your rows to columns.

[**SQL FIDDLE DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5b47e/1)

```
SELECT *
FROM  (SELECT il.IssueID,
              l.Location,
              i.IssueTitle,
              lt.Type
       FROM   Locations l
              JOIN LocationTypes lt
                ON l.TypeID = lt.TypeID
              JOIN IssueLocations il
                ON il.LocationId = l.LocaltionID
              JOIN issues i
                ON i.IssueID = il.IssueID) a
      PIVOT (Max(location)
            FOR type IN([Building],
                        [Floor],
                        [Room]))piv
```

Comment: There might be more or less location types.  No hard coding of columns.